# Cost of upgrading Mathematica student version to professional version?

Tags: licensing

The [Wolfram site](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/pricing/students.php) mentions that the student version of Mathematica can be upgraded to a professional version at a *significant discount*. However, they do not mention any prices on the web page and suggest to ask them directly via email. Being a student myself, I am currently using the student version of Mathematica, and I wonder how much the upgrade will tentatively cost me once I graduate. (Since this time has not come yet, I don't want to waste their time by asking directly yet.) Does anyone know how much such an upgrade would cost?

Comment: You shouldn't lose access to your student license when you graduate. Wolfram doesn't want you to use the student version after, but as long as your intuition maintains the license you can keep upgrading your version. Keep in mind though that the student license does not permit most things beyond recreational and academic purposes, especially for profit development.

Comment: You mean, you'd rather waste our time, instead of people paid to answer such questions?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I meant, since I am not going to upgrade *right now*, I am not buying anything, which makes contacting their sales department not appropriate. The stackexchange site on the other hand is put in place solely for the purpose of asking and answering questions. I am sorry if you feel like this is a waste of your time.